# What HTML elements can be made clickable with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I just started learning JavaScript and one of the first pieces of codes I've come across is onclick.

The only example I've seen it being used in are form buttons for example:

```
<input type="button" onclick="checkName()" value="Check name" />
```

I'm curious as to what other html elements can be made clickable to run javascript?

It would be great if you could list every possible type, thanks!

Comment: I think most of the elements could be, BTW here are a tons of elements & I am not sure for all

Comment: any element inside of your browser window is clickable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every element can be made clickable.

Answer (score 1):

onclick can be used with the following tags:

```
<a> <abbr> <acronym> <address> <area> <b> <big> <blockquote> <body> <button> <caption>     <center> <cite> <code> <col> <colgroup> <dd> <del> <dfn> <dir> <div> <dl> <dt> <em> <fieldset> <form> <h1> <h2> <h3> <h4> <h5> <h6> <hr> <i> <img> <input> <ins> <kbd> <label> <legend> <li> <link> <map> <menu> <noframes> <noscript> <object> <ol> <optgroup> <option> <p> <pre> <q> <s> <samp> <select> <small> <span> <strike> <strong> <sub> <sup> <table> <tbody> <td> <textarea> <tfoot> <th> <thead> <tr> <tt> <u> <ul> <var>
```

edit..
Its easier to say wich ones do not support onclick:

```
<base> <bdo> <br> <head> <html> <iframe> <meta> <param> <script> <style> <title>
```

Comment: Why downvotes? He didn't mention html 5 tags but it's more accurate than "all" (because, for example, BR is not)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - Not my downvote but there are a couple of problems with this answer. First, which elements are "clickable" and which HTML 4.01 validly take an onclick attribute are not the same thing. `addEventListener` can be used on elements regardless. Second, while it might be true that a `<br>` cannot be clicked, several of the others listed are clickable in some situations.

Comment: @Alohci I agree about that distinction but (well, guessing a little bit) OP was asking for elements with onclick attribute. Both "everything" and this list are not complete answers (I like this one because, at least, it shows that _click_  for some elements may not have any sense).